# Foreign Key value assigning in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project in **Django** where two custom build user model is used.

1. `Industry`
2. `Employee`

Here every `Industry` user will entry some of their `Employee`'s data, and later on `Employee` will verify and finish to create his account.

my **models.py**:

```
class myCustomeUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique="True", blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    is_Employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Inspector = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Industry = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Industry(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='industry_releted_user')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    license = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    industry_extrafield = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='employee_releted_user', blank=True)
    #industry = models.OneToOneField(Industry, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee_releted_industry')
    industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    i_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    gmail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=True)
    employee_varified = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
```

Now I wrote the following code in **views.py** to create an `Employee`'s entry by `Industry` user when the `Industry` user signed in from their account:

```
@method_decorator(industry_required, name='dispatch')
class industryDetails(DetailView):

    model = Industry
    template_name = 'app/industryDetails.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Industry.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Industry, user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['inserted_text'] = "inserted text from EmployeeDetails of views.py"

        return context

def employeeRegister_byIndustry(request):
    employeeRegister_dict={
        'insert_me' : "hello this is extra inserted"
    }
    if request.method == "POST":
        this_i_id = request.POST['i_id']
        this_name = request.POST['name']
        this_rank = request.POST['rank']
        this_gmail = request.POST['gmail']
        this_industry = self.request.user.industry_releted_user

        employee_obj = Employee.objects.create(industry=this_industry, i_id=this_i_id, name=this_name, rank=this_rank, gmail=this_gmail)
        employee_obj.save()
        if employee_obj.is_valid():
            print('valid employee Object')
        return redirect('app:employeeSignup')

    return render(request, 'app/employeeSignup.html', employeeRegister_dict)
```

and my **template** (`industryDetails.html`):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row m-0">
    <div class="col-xl-10 mx-auto">
      <p>inserted text: {{ inserted_text }}</p>
      <hr>
      <h3>Username: {{ industry.user }}</h3>
      <p>name: {{ industry.name }}</p>
      <p>owner: {{ industry.owner }}</p>
      <p>license: {{ industry.license }}</p>
      <p>id: {{ industry.user.id }}</p>
      <p>username: {{ industry.user.username }}</p>
      <p>password: {{ industry.user.password }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="my-5"></div>
<hr>
<div class="my-5"></div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row m-0">
    <div class="col-xl-8">

    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3">
      <h3>Add new Employee</h3>
      <form class="" action="{% url 'app:employeeRegister_byIndustry' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Enter industrial id</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="i_id" placeholder="Industrial id">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Enter employee name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Employee name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>rank</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rank" placeholder="rank">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Enter employee's gmail</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="gmail" placeholder="gmail">
        </div>
        <a href="#"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Submit</button> </a>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But here the **Foreign Key** assignment does not working as I want. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.request.user` is a user model *object*, so in thus case a `myCustomUser` object, not an `Industry` object. You can access the related `Industry` object with:

```
this_industry = request.user.industry_releted_user
```

This is thus the name of the relation from `Industry` to `myCustomUser` in *reverse*, the name of that relation is determined by the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

I would also advise to make use of [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) to validate and clean user input. A POST request can lack certain data or can be forged, so `request.POST` will for example not per see contain a value for `name`. A form makes it convenient to validate that all required data is present, check if the email address is indeed a valid email address, and convert data from a string-like object to a python object that is more specific to the model field.

Comment: now it says `name 'self' is not defined` after submitting the form

Comment: @KanchonGharami: that would be the same with your `self.request.user`, since it is (likely) a function-based view...

Comment: @KanchonGharami: it is thus `request.user.industry_releted_user`.

Comment: no, actually they are in different `view`, I have just edited my question by full `views.py`, please check and help me to solve

Comment: @KanchonGharami: the creation of the `Employee` happens in a function-based view...

Comment: Now it says `DatabaseError at /employeeRegister_byIndustry/
No exception message supplied`

Comment: @KanchonGharami: you did not provide a `user=...` when creating the `Employee`, which of course is not possible, since at that time there is no user yet.... You need to revise the modeling.

Comment: oh yeah, that means if I want to entry any `Employee` without providing a `user`, then I need to place the primary key in my `Industry` instead of  `myCustomeUser` right?

Comment: @KanchonGharami: I think you should probably create a user for that `Employee` in the view and then link it, but probably you should go back to the drawing table, and first determine *what* the view is all supposed to do, since right now, this is a bit of an inconsistency.